# How to get value of passed parameter in controller by Block in magento?

Tags: php, magento

I have passes value from controller like

```
{{block type="test/test" name="test123" catstatus="xyz" template="storelocator/abc.phtml" }}
```

i am trying to get value of `catstatus` on abc.phtml page by

```
$this->getData('catstatus');
```

i am able to get this on the phtml page

**but I am not getting blankstring when get this value on my indexcontroller.php**

Please suggest a possible solution.

Comment: What code are you using on `indexcontroller.php`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer below code

```
//Loading current layout
$this->loadLayout();
//Creating a new block
$block = $this->getLayout()->createBlock(
'Mage_Core_Block_Template',
'test_block_name',
array('template' => 'page/html/testblock.phtml')
);

$this->getLayout()->getBlock('content')->append($block);

//Now showing it with rendering of layout
$this->renderLayout();
```